# How to generate column update option in model create net core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I use NetCore 2.1 SDK, database is Mysql (5.7.21) with Pomelo package connector (2.1 RC2).

I have "updateAt" column in my database table, type datetime.

I have scaffolded database where column was:

```
`UpdatedAt` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

after creating migration, the result is:

```
entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt)
                        .HasColumnType("datetime")
                        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

When I run database update, column is missing "ON UPDATE" option.

How could I change modelCreate to achieve this?

Comment: Hmm, curious about this as well. I have properties like `entityTypeBuilder.Property(x => x.CreatedDateUtc).HasColumnType("TIMESTAMP").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` in my project. The timestamps are automatically created, but presumably by the .NET application and not the database since the date column in the database doesn't have a DEFAULT specified.